# ARCore augmented Images not tracking outside

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, augmentedimage

I'm working on an app with Unity, in which I want to use ARCore's augemented Images to track Images outside, specifically Images of streetart. I took the pictures and when testing them at home on my Monitor they are easily found, but when I'm trying it in the real world, it does not work. Somehow the pictures are not recognized. I've tried about 20 different pictures of different designs and none of them worked outside. I also ran all of them through the arcoreimg tool and they all performed at 85-100, which is considered good.
I'm stumped on how that could be and would appreciate any ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: What Unity version do you develop in and have you ensured that when testing outside the app had the right camera permissions? What phone OS are you testing on?

Comment: It may be the difference between additive light (screen) and subtractive light (paint). Try testing at home on a printed picture. If not, try it from a different device and see if its something specific to the camera sensors...

Comment: @Doh09 The Unity version is 2019.3.15f1 and I'm testing it on a OnePlus 5T with Android 10. The camera permission should be given, since I tested it on my computer screen before going outside.

Comment: I also tested the suggestion of @Yin and tested it on printed out pictures and that worked. I'll try to get another phone and test it on that.

Comment: Just a theory, maybe a library you use requires there to be a good data connection or WiFi? For example if some of the processing happens in the cloud.

Comment: Also I will advise you to try upgrade to the latest Unity version. I worked on a project earlier where the AR experience seemed improved and a camera permission error was fixed by just upgrading to a newer Unity version.